# Impact of declaring multiple classes

Tags: .net, performance

In my .Net application (MVVM application) i have let's say 10 drop down lists. So i created 10 different classes(Models) containing just Name , Value pair. The reason of creating 10 different classes is just because these drop down lists are functionally independent.

What are the pros and cons (Including memory impact) of 10 different classes instead of just 1 class (Which contains Name Value Pair and Bound to View through ViewModel)

Comment: Do you mean "10 different classes" or do you mean "10 instances of the same class?"  Perhaps you could post some simplified code to demonstrate the two approaches.

Comment: These are just 10 different class in solution instead of just a one single class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a number of different classes over a single one is hardly likely to make a difference to your application. Instantiation of simple types is very fast (billions of objects a second).

You *might* notice issues if you go into the many many millions of objects and then only if you are doing work when instantiating them.

Comment: How the memory allocation will work when 10 different classes are used bound to 10 different drop down lists and Just 1 class is used to bind 10 different drop down lists (Means: Instead of StudentList, CustomerList i declare DropDownListItems containing ID and Name variables)

Comment: @user1386121 - Does it matter? These are **micro**-optimizations. You need to ensure your code is correct and readable (easily understandable) before you worry about performance. And even then, you should first measure and find bottlenecks before fixing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Having an extra 10 (or even 100) small classes in your application (as opposed to 1 class with a shared role) is going to have **essentially no impact on performance**.

That said, more classes means more code to maintain which means more work for you.  If these classes are actually different then having a different class for each control is quite possibly the best decision, however if all these classes are essentially identical then personally I'd rather save myself some typing and use something like [KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx?ppud=4) instead.